# How to split the text data after getting from api in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I want to split the text data in Text widget after getting from api call. Here is the code

```
Row(
children:<Widget>[
Text('result'),
Text(item[pos].asr), //getting the data from api call which is "22:00"
RaisedButton(
onpressed(){
print()// here i want to show the split text data which is "22" then "00" under "22"
}
),
]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let try it:

```
Row(
      children:<Widget>[
        Text('result'),
        Text(item[pos].asr),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            List<String> arr = item[pos].asr.split(':');
            int hour = int.parse(arr[0]);
            int minutes = int.parse(arr[1]);
            print(hour.toString() + " " + minutes.toString());
          },
        ),
      ]
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split using `split` function as:

```
List<String> splitted = item[pos].asr.split(":"); // list containing 22 and 00.
```

to print 22, use -> `splitted[0]`
and for 00, use -> `splitted[1]`

Comment: Already Text(item[pos].asr) has the data which displays 22:00 when i run on mobile screen, you have mention the 'hardcoded' declared string.

Answer (score 0):

**you can store splitted value in list**

```
var string = "22:00"; 
List splitedText = string.split(":");
print(splitedText[0]);
print(splitedText[1]);
```

Comment: Already Text(item[pos].asr) has the data which displays 22:00 when i run on mobile screen, you have mention the 'hardcoded' declared string.